# Installing Craft in a Sub Folder

Tags: url, redirect, install, htaccess, apache

I have created a Craft CMS site on a VPS Server running CentOS 7. I have a file setup on the public_html like this: -

- cms

  - craft
  - public
- app (this is running a Symfony Framework Web App and runs from app.example.com perfectly)

Now I have the site working from www.example.com but when I login to the back office all of the links say... https://www.example.com/cms/public/admin/dashboard. I want to remove cms/public from the URL links in the back office.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to do some URL rewriting with an .htaccess file or similar depending on your setup. Looks like this question might already have an [answer over here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13717/remove-subdirectories-from-admin-url-with-htaccess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I actually managed to fix this. I moved the index.php file from the cms/public subfolder to public_html and it worked a treat. I had to change the following code:

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../craft';
```

to

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = 'cms/craft';
```